# Rewrite Slug for CPT Archive Pages to Plural Name of Slug

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a custom post type with the rewritten slug of `plugin` creating the url structure of http://site.com/plugin/plugin-slug/. Which makes the CPT Archive as http://site.com/plugin/

I'd like to rewrite it, without using a page and a custom page template, to use http://site.com/plugins/ (Which is the `labels=>Name` in the CPT). while keeping the slug for the single posts as `/plugin/`
This would also need to support things like `/plugins/page/21 - which it currently does.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you register the post type, set the argument `'has_archive'` to a string, in your case `plugins`.

The doc block for `register_post_type()` says:

> `@type bool|string $has_archive`
>   Whether there should be post type archives, or if a string, the
>   archive slug to use. Will generate the proper rewrite rules if
>   `$rewrite` is enabled. Default `false`.

Minified example:

```
register_post_type( 'plugin', [ 'has_archive' => 'plugins' ] );
```

Comment: To refresh the rewrite rules for a custom post type you are updating, visit **Settings > Permalinks**. Based on the example above, if you don't do this, `/plugin` will still be the archive slug and `/plugins` won't work yet.